# Should I charge my clients for software fees?

Tags: pay-rate, software, web-development

When initially starting my business, I took on many different tools to improve my service to my clients as a website developer & digital marketer.

I've reached a point where as I diversify my service and gain more and more clients, the amount of software used and the fees involved have become quite expensive.

Is it suggested to charge clients a fee for my software use in the service or should this be embedded in the hourly rate?

Comment: Why downvote? Please explain so i can improve my questions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cost of doing business should be calculated as your *overhead* when figuring out your rates.

The tools you need to complete your work should *never* be directly invoiced to clients.

If you hire someone to paint your house, you'd be pretty upset if they charged you for ladders, scaffolds, and drop cloths. Those are standard tools for the work.

Clients should only ever be invoiced for *specific* items which are unique to the project(s). i.e. you'd pay for the paint to paint your house.